# Fetch Static files from Server in Django

Tags: python, django, static-content

I'm using a development server for django. I want to grab my static files from a server. htts://www.example.com/static

How do I do this in Django?

Currently I'm trying to to change the STATIC_URL from '/static/' , but it fails whenever I change it. By fail I mean that the html still loads, but the site can't access and load my static files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [External Static Files Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368780/external-static-files-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the url of the static that will be used in template `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

add the desire path to the static files dirs var

`STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/var/www/my_site/my_path',)`

please note that the path **doesn't end with backslash**

please note that the **trailing comma**

now in your templates use

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

this link will resolve to `my_site/static/css/style.css`
and will be in the folder `/var/www/my_site/my_path/css/style.css`

**`href=`**`"my_site/static/css/style.css"`
maps to

**`STATICFILES_DIRS`** : `/var/www/my_site/my_path/css/style.css`

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm calling an server using https. I can't just give a /path/to/directory

Comment: Giving these absolute path is done in the settings, and using it in the templates has nothing to do with https, or at least that is how i imagine it ,Checking the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/ doesn't mention anything about the https